# VaadinSession failing in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session, vaadin8

I'm trying to make a simple Vaadin application integrated with Spring Boot / Spring Session / Spring Security, nothing too fancy since the client requirements aren't that demanding. I managed to set up a basic environment with Spring Session JDBC and added a couple of `View`s.

```
@SpringUI
@SpringViewDisplay
public class MyUI extends UI implements ViewDisplay {

    private Panel springViewDisplay;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5326618953003021331L;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
        root.setSizeFull();
        setContent(root);

        final CssLayout navigationBar = new CssLayout();
        navigationBar.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LAYOUT_COMPONENT_GROUP);
        navigationBar.addComponent(createNavigationButton("Nómina",
            DefaultView.VIEW_NAME));
        navigationBar.addComponent(createNavigationButton("Empleados",
            EmpleadosAdminView.VIEW_NAME));
        root.addComponent(navigationBar);

        springViewDisplay = new Panel();
        springViewDisplay.setSizeFull();
        root.addComponent(springViewDisplay);
        root.setExpandRatio(springViewDisplay, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

The `DefaultView` loads fine:

```
@SpringView(name = DefaultView.VIEW_NAME)
public class DefaultView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    public static final String VIEW_NAME = "";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3600517630040771693L;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        addComponent(new Label("Default view"));
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
    // This view is constructed in the init() method()
    }
}
```

The second view, however, throws the following exception when accessing it:

```
@SpringView(name = EmpleadosAdminView.VIEW_NAME)
public class EmpleadosAdminView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    public static final String VIEW_NAME = "empleados";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3344332615518673282L;

    private final EmpleadoRepository empleadoRepository;
    private final EmpleadosEditor empleadosEditor;

    private final Grid<Empleado> grid;

    private final TextField filter;

    private final Button addNewEmpleado;

    @Autowired
    public EmpleadosAdminView(EmpleadoRepository empleadoRepository, EmpleadosEditor empleadosEditor) {
        this.empleadoRepository = empleadoRepository;
        this.empleadosEditor = empleadosEditor;
        this.grid = new Grid<>(Empleado.class);
        this.filter = new TextField();
        this.addNewEmpleado = new Button("Agregar nuevo empleado", VaadinIcons.PLUS);
    }

    private void listEmpleados(String filterText) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(filterText)) {
           grid.setItems(empleadoRepository.findAll());
        } else {
        grid.setItems(empleadoRepository.findByNombreIgnoreCase(filterText));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
        HorizontalLayout actions = new HorizontalLayout(filter, addNewEmpleado);
        VerticalLayout mainLayout = new VerticalLayout(actions, grid, empleadosEditor);
        addComponent(mainLayout);

        grid.setHeight(300, Unit.PIXELS);
        grid.setColumns("id", "nombre", "cedula");

    filter.setPlaceholder("Filtrar por nombre");

    filter.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY);
    filter.addValueChangeListener(e -> listEmpleados(e.getValue()));

    grid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(e ->
            empleadosEditor.editEmpleado(e.getValue())
    );

    addNewEmpleado.addClickListener(e -> empleadosEditor.editEmpleado(new Empleado()));

    empleadosEditor.setChangeHandler(() -> {
        empleadosEditor.setVisible(false);
        listEmpleados(filter.getValue());
    });

    listEmpleados(null);
}
}
```

> Hibernate: 
>       select
>           empleado0_.id as id1_0_,
>           empleado0_.activo as activo2_0_,
>           empleado0_.cedula as cedula3_0_,
>           empleado0_.nombre as nombre4_0_ 
>       from
>           Empleado empleado0_
>
> 2018-03-20 19:07:21.222  WARN 13380 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod          : Error in serialization of the application: Class com.tomasa.nomina.ui.EmpleadosEditor$$Lambda$658/1513980400 must implement serialization.
>
> 2018-03-20 19:07:21.230 ERROR 13380 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler    :
>
> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object] to type [byte[]] for value 'com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession@22659fd5'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:46) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.serialize(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:575) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.access$500(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:130) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository$2.lambda$doInTransactionWithoutResult$2(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:440) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:853) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:850) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:905) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository$2.doInTransactionWithoutResult(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:437) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:36) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.save(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:409) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.save(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:130) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:228) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:196) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper.onResponseCommitted(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:184) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.doOnResponseCommitted(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:227) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.checkContentLength(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:217) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.trackContentLength(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:177) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.access$1100(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:38) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:613) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:633) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:633) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.commitJsonResponse(UIInitHandler.java:126) ~[vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
>       at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:109) ~[vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
>       at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
>       at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601) ~[vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
>       at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445) [vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:146) [spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81) [spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]

I'm basing my code on these tutorials:

http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/
https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if there's some configuration I need to revise. The basic authentication configuration is this:

### JDBCHttpSessionConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class JdbcHttpSessionConfig {
}
```

### SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable() // Use Vaadin's CSRF protection
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated() // User must be authenticated to access any part of the application
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/*"); // Static resources are ignored
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line from the log reveals the core problem:

```
2018-03-20 19:07:21.222 WARN 13380 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod : Error in serialization of the application: Class com.tomasa.nomina.ui.EmpleadosEditor$$Lambda$658/1513980400 must implement serialization.
```

Since `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` [uses standard Java serialization](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/jdbc/JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java#L545-L552) while storing the sessions, you have to ensure that the attributes you put in session implement `Serializable`. In your case class `com.tomasa.nomina.ui.EmpleadosEditor$$Lambda$658/1513980400` looks like the offender that doesn't comply with that requirement.

You should probably double check your app for all the objects that end up placed in session and have them implement `Serializable` contract.

Comment: I did notice this and I added `(Button.ClickListener & Serializable) e-> //...` to every lambda in the class but the warning still appears for the same class and the error too.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem? The root cause is `NotSerializableException` so you're definitely trying to persist something to session that isn't `Serializable`.

Comment: Progress is at https://github.com/Firebeam/nomina-tomasa . There's not much implemented so I uploaded the whole project.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. As suspected, your classes (`EmpleadosEditor`, `EmpleadosAdminView`) are not serializable since they hold a reference to `EmpleadoRepository` whose implementation isn't serializable. I haven't used Vaadin for 5+ years, so I can't point you in the right direction how to address this, but I believe you should obtain a reference to `EmpleadoRepository` in your UI components by other means than autowiring, potentially using `ServletContext`.

Comment: Ok, so I began having suspicions about the `@Autowired` constructors. I substituted the constructor with a `@PostConstruct` method in `EmpleadosEditor` and the error "moved" to `EmpleadosAdminView`. I moved along that path until I hit the repository layer, and... back to where I started. I felt like I learned a bit more, though and I feel the issue should be around that.

Comment: I looked at the trace, the warning is gone but the original error remains: `org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object] to type [byte[]] for value 'com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession@d47c2bd'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor`

Comment: Again, your classes cannot be serialized due to the references to `EmpleadoRepository` whose implementation is provided by Spring Data. IMO you should try the approach with resolving bean through `ServletContext`, using something like `VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext()` and then obtain Spring context using `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sc)`. At that point you can obtain a reference to `EmpleadoRepository`.